# python, power function using one loop

Tags: python

I tried to solve a problem, writing a power by function that does the same job as the operator ** (by python for example)
after I solve it, I got another assignment:
I'm allowed to use only one loop and only one if\else.

I would love for some insight 
I'm a beginer and have no clue how to go further.

my code was:
...

```
def power(x, y):
    s = x
    if y > 0:
        for i in range (1, y):
            s = s * x
    elif (y < 0):
        for i in range (y, -1):
            s = s * x
        s = 1 / s
    else:
        s = 1

    return s

print(power(3, 5))
print(power(3, -5))
print(power(3, 0))
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: ye actually your code looks good,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allowed to use the `abs` function?

```
from typing import Union


def power(x: Union[float, int], y: int) -> Union[float, int]:
    s: Union[float, int] = 1
    for _ in range(abs(y)):
        s *= x
    if y < 0:
        s = 1 / s
    return s


assert power(3, 5) == 243
assert 0.0040 < power(3, -5) < 0.0042
assert power(3, 0) == 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution.
I wonder, why did you use the Union func?

as i turns, it workes without it...
...
def power_t(x, y):
    s = 1
    for num in range(abs(y)):
        s*= x
    if y < 0:
        s = 1 / s
    return s
    
    
power_t(3, 5)
power_t(2, 7)

Comment: It's a type annotation to indicate that the return value and `x` can both be either a `float` or `int`, but `y` must be an `int` specifically (the loop won't work if you pass a `float` value for `y`).  This is one respect in which this isn't a perfect replacement for the `**` operator, but I don't think you can make it handle floating point exponents within the constraints you've given.

Answer (score 0):

A way I would do it is creating a function that accepts a number and an exponent.
Then I would create a list with exp amount of that number. Multiply everything in the list together to get the result:

```
def power(num, exp):
    prod = 1
    powers = [num] * exp
    for n in powers:
        prod *= n
    return prod
```

Comment: This only works if `exp` is positive. `2**-2 == power(2,-2)` -> `False`.

Comment: I need to cover also the possibility that exp is either negative or zero